# Invoke function defined as onload event

Tags: javascript

I tried to invoke a function from markup in the following way:

```
<form onsibmit="actualizeTextFields()">
    <!-- Form's stuff -->
</form>
```

Where the funcition defined as follows:

```
window.onload = function actualizeTextFields(){
    //some stuff
};
```

And it didn't work. I thought that the name actualizeTextFields would be added to the global `Environment record`. Why isn't it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named function expressions only create a variable matching their name **inside** their own scope (except in old versions of Internet Explorer thanks to a bug).

Function declarations will create the variable in the **current** scope.

You could rewrite your code as:

```
function actualizeTextFields(){
    //some stuff
};
window.onload = actualizeTextFields;
```

or

```
function actualizeTextFields(){
    //some stuff
};
window.addEventListener('load', actualizeTextFields);
```

Comment: You don't need semicolon after function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If you assing function to varaible or property it will become expression and if you name it, it will be local inside the function. the solution is to define it first:

```
function actualizeTextFields(){
    //some stuff
}
window.onload = actualizeTextFields;
```